# What is a command sequence in Git to allow basic usage for beginners?

Tags: git

I'm faced with the challenge that I'd like to simplify the life of extreme beginner users, which however have to share files through Git. They are rather overwhelmed and even the order of most basic Git commands is error-prone with them.

So I'd like to provide a single command `save` which adds, commits, pushes, pulls all at once in a way that basic work is possible for them. They will never touch branches. They will rarely edit the same files.

Can you come up with a single script which will synchronize with Git and work "most of the time"?

Maybe you can point out at which point I can integrate a merging tool like `meld`, too. I know it will all be inefficient, but at least they can work.

Unfortunately, no alternative is an option (replace Git, better knowledge, ...).

Comment: Mercurial (`hg`) is as capable as Git and *much* more beginner-friendly. It's just not as popular (nor as fast). Hg is available on all the same platforms, as far as I know, not that I know that far. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to add a pull in the script or else users will have to manually pull to make sure they are at the head. Adding a stash will also make it more robust in case users do happen to touch the same files.

```
#!/bin/bash

git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
if [ $? -eq 0]
then
  git add -A
  git commit -m "$1"
  git push origin master
else
  echo "ERROR: Merge conflict!"
fi
```

You could then save this script at /usr/local/bin and the script could be invoked by name and with a single argument that gets set to the commit description.

Comment: Git stash, +1..

Comment: Checking the exit code of `stash pop` is important. If there are conflicts you don't want 'add', 'commit' and 'push' to happen with no opportunity to fix or abort.

Comment: good point. definitely want to check for conflicts or else your files will get fubard.

Comment: Thanks! I'll guess I will even spare them the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're all on unix machines.

Have them all add this to their `.bash_profile`.

```
function save(){
    git stash;
    # might want to replace `master` with 
    # whatever branch they are pushing to.
    git pull origin master;
    git stash pop;
    git add --all;
    git commit -m "$1";
    git push origin master;
}
```

This way they will have access to this simple function from the command line.
You could even write some checks to see if they give the correct number of arguments ect.
Example usage:

```
save "did the thing I was supposed to do";
```

You could also try having them use a GUI for git.

Comment: It seems you need commit your changes before pull

Comment: Suppose `stash pop` fails, with your function implementation 'add', 'commit' and 'push' will all be executed regardless.